# RecyclerView Adapter Listener Callback When Dataset Changes

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Is there anyway to know when the Recycler's view Adapter finishes updating the dataset?

For example i want to call a callback when

```
notifyItemRangeInserted(0, companyList.size());
```

finishes and has updated the new list.

My problem is that if i execute this code synchronously, the progress bar disappears first showing the old list and then immediately refreshes to the new one.

Any ideas?

```
 notifyItemRangeInserted(0, companyList.size());
 progressVisibilityCallback.setVisibility(false);
```

Comment: It's because the list is updating in async. There is no listener for list updating. You may do some workaround for it, like stopping progress in a thread after some delay... I don't really know but you can play with createViewHolder() to identify if the list is up to dated or not